Neo4j GraphRAG Document Insertion but nothing is coming in my Neo4j Workspace

import logging
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
from neo4j_graphrag.indexes import upsert_vector
import openai
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# Set up logging to both file and console
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,  # Log level
    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",  # Log format
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("pdf_processing.log"),  # Log to file
        logging.StreamHandler()  # Log to console
    ]
)

URI = URI
AUTH = ("neo4j", "PWD")

# Set your OpenAI API key here
openai.api_key = openaikey

# Connect to Neo4j database
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(URI, auth=AUTH)

# Function to extract text from a PDF file
def get_pdf_text(pdf_path):
    logging.info(f"Starting PDF text extraction from: {pdf_path}")
    text = ""
    pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_path)
    for page_num, page in enumerate(pdf_reader.pages):
        extracted_text = page.extract_text() if page.extract_text() else ''
        text += extracted_text
        logging.info(f"Extracted text from page {page_num + 1}: {len(extracted_text)} characters")
    logging.info(f"Completed text extraction, total length: {len(text)} characters")
    return text

# Function to split the extracted text into chunks
def get_text_chunks(text, chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200):
    logging.info(f"Starting text splitting into chunks, chunk size: {chunk_size}, overlap: {chunk_overlap}")
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=chunk_size, chunk_overlap=chunk_overlap)
    chunks = text_splitter.split_text(text)
    logging.info(f"Completed text splitting. Total chunks created: {len(chunks)}")
    return chunks

# Function to generate text embedding for a given chunk
def get_text_embedding(text_chunk):
    logging.info(f"Generating embedding for chunk of size {len(text_chunk)}")
    response = openai.Embedding.create(
        input=text_chunk,
        model="text-embedding-ada-002"  # OpenAI's embedding model (1536-dimensional vector)
    )
    embedding = response['data'][0]['embedding']  # Extract the embedding vector
    logging.info(f"Generated embedding vector of length {len(embedding)}")
    return embedding

# Function to process a PDF, chunk the text, generate embeddings, and upsert vectors into Neo4j
def process_pdf_and_upsert_vectors(pdf_path):
    logging.info(f"Starting processing of PDF: {pdf_path}")
    
    # Step 1: Extract the text from the PDF
    text = get_pdf_text(pdf_path)

    # Step 2: Split the text into chunks
    chunks = get_text_chunks(text)

    # Step 3: Loop through each chunk and generate embeddings
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        embedding = get_text_embedding(chunk)
        
        # Step 4: Upsert the vector into Neo4j (node_id can be dynamic)
        logging.info(f"Upserting vector for chunk {i + 1}")
        upsert_vector(
            driver,
            node_id=i + 1,  # Assuming each chunk gets a new node
            embedding_property="vectorProperty",
            vector=embedding,
        )
        logging.info(f"Upserted vector for node {i + 1}")
    
    logging.info(f"Completed processing of PDF: {pdf_path}")

# Example usage:
process_pdf_and_upsert_vectors(pdf_path)


I read the official documentation of Neo4j and tried to implement the RAG by using that but no output is coming and also i tried to extract the text from the pdf document convert that into chunks and then upserting into neo4j but still the output is nothing and there is no embeddings in my Neo4j Workspace
Can anyone help me to solve the issue so i can insert my embeddings into the neo4j and then do the vector search based on the user query !
